# check my work on this problem: given tan(2x), find sin x + cos x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

$\tan 2x = - 24/7$

$90^\circ < x < 180^\circ$.

Find the value of $\sin x+\cos x$.

What I have so far:

$\tan(2x) = -\frac{24}{7} \Rightarrow \frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^{2}x} = -\frac{24}{7}$.

Cross-multiplying gives us the quadratic $12\tan^{2}x-7\tan(x)-12 = 0$, factorized, it is $(3\tan x-4)(4\tan x+3) \Rightarrow \tan x = \frac{4}{3}, -\frac{3}{4}$. Since $90^\circ < x < 180^\circ$, I would have to pay attention to $\tan x = -\frac{3}{4}$.

$\sin(\arctan(-\frac{3}{4}))+\cos(\arctan(-\frac{3}{4}))$. When calculating this, I got $\frac{1}{5}$, but that was incorrect. Where did I make my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close - basically correct in fact. The only issue I see is that in your calculation of $\sin\arctan\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)$ and $\cos\arctan\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)$, you forgot the angles needed to be in the range $90^\circ$ to $180^\circ$, so you need a positive $\sin$ and negative $\cos$. If you just plug it into a calculator, you will get the wrong answer because the standard range on $\arctan$ is $-90^\circ$ to $90^\circ$.

Comment: @MathyPerson Glad to help!